# Take an input from a combo box in Windows Mobile Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, windows-phone, mobile-application

I have the following combo box in the Mobile App

```
<ComboBox name="cmb_tax" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
      <ComboBoxItem content="10%" />
      <ComboBoxItem content="20%" />
      <ComboBoxItem content="30%" />
</ComboBox>
```

and want to take the value passed from this to a string variable. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((ComboBoxItem)cmb_tax.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: Also how to take an input from <DatePicker name="dp"> and assign in to a variable? Is it like `DateTime in=this.dp.Value;`?